# Blur the mat-select angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have form with mat-select and input when hit enter blur all element of form and execute search function. When I pick a select in mat-select and hit enter, mat-select still focus on its so it open while search function is running. I need a function to blur mat-select (mat-select below is grey not violet) to prevent them open when I click enter.

My code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focus-select-afterload-n99bzu?file=main.ts

Thank for attention!

[image: The image of select when i selected a selection]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
this.myForm.disable();
```

to disable your form if you want to disable only dropdown then you have to call

```
this.myForm.controls['category_food'].disable()
```

then enable it according to your logic(i am enabling it after 3 seconds). i have edited your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focus-select-afterload-wem6xp). mark accepted if this answers your query or ask in comments if in doubt, would be happy to help you.

Comment: i mean i need code for blur mat-select like you type input(<form [formGroup]="myForm" (keydown.enter)="$event.target.blur();">) and press enter but mat-select doesn't work with $event.target.blur();.

Comment: yep you cannot blurr element with event object because event object only carries info about the event which was triggered(input keyup event here). if you want to disable element you can have an element reference in typescript and can disable by that. another way is what i have implemented [here] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-focus-select-afterload-wem6xp)